# Read an excel file, manipulate the data but retain the original formatting using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe

I have code that essentially reads an excel file, that excel file has a header / filter on the first few lines, then the columns are below that. I have to load that into a dataframe, apply a filter and then export out to a new excel.

The issue however is that once exported, I obviously loose the header/filter.. I need to ensure my final result contains those first 3 rows as I use this file with a later script and it requires the format of the original file.

I have an excel file that looks like:

```
+----------------+-----------+-------+--------+--+
| My Report      |           |       |        |  |
+----------------+-----------+-------+--------+--+
| Report Filters | Include X |       |        |  |
+----------------+-----------+-------+--------+--+
|                |           |       |        |  |
+----------------+-----------+-------+--------+--+
| Name           | ID        | My ID | Status |  |
+----------------+-----------+-------+--------+--+
| test           | 1234      | 4321  | Open   |  |
+----------------+-----------+-------+--------+--+
```

My columns in this sample is "Name, ID etc".

When I do my filtering and export to excel, I loose the first 3 rows (My report etc).

My goal is to keep the first 3 rows. Everything else works except for that.

I tried concatenating the dataframes but then I end up with a wonky result.

Code (I changed variable names etc to keep it as a sample):

```
# Store the original dataset as is for later use (rebuild with header/filter rows)
        self.original_data = pd.read_excel('original-data.xlsx')

        # New dataframe copied from original, used for filtering data
        self.new_data = pd.DataFrame(self.original_data.values[3:],
                                             columns=self.original_data.iloc[2])

        # Filter the data
        self.filtered_data = self.new_data[self.new_data[self.filter_column].isin(self.filtered_list)]

        # Grabs first three rows of original to keep integrity
        self.filtered_data = pd.concat(objs=[
            self.original_data.iloc[:3],
            self.filtered_data])

        self.filtered_data.to_excel('filtered_data/new-data.xlsx',
            sheet_name='Yay',
            index=False
        )
```

Comment: I remember read_excel has a parameter to skip the rows.

Comment: Yeah header & skip rows but I need those retained in my final result. The way I wrote this is to read the initial file once, then keep a backup of it so I can in a way, go back and parse the first 3 lines, take them and apply it to my new DF but when doing that (concat), I end up with a wonky result.

Answer (score 0):

I was overthinking this solution but turned out to be straight forward after playing around with it for a bit.

I need to add an additional line to match the columns between both DF (since they are different), then do my concat and thats that!.

New additional line before concat:

```
# Rename the columns of the filtered data to match the columns of the original data (used for concat)
self.filtered_data.columns = self.new_data.columns
```

Full code complete:

```
  # Store the original dataset as is for later use (rebuild with header/filter rows)
self.original_data = pd.read_excel('original-data.xlsx')

    # New dataframe copied from original, used for filtering data
    self.new_data = pd.DataFrame(self.original_data.values[3:],
                                         columns=self.original_data.iloc[2])

    # Filter the data
    self.filtered_data = self.new_data[self.new_data[self.filter_column].isin(self.filtered_list)]

# Rename the columns of the filtered data to match the columns of the original data (used for concat)
self.filtered_data.columns = self.new_data.columns

    # Grabs first three rows of original to keep integrity
    self.filtered_data = pd.concat(objs=[
        self.original_data.iloc[:3],
        self.filtered_data])

    self.filtered_data.to_excel('filtered_data/new-data.xlsx',
        sheet_name='Yay',
        index=False
    )
```